# Is it possible to keep thread context in async await in rust?

Tags: rust

Can Rust's Async/Await Model Support Thread Local Variables Like Traditional Threaded Models?

I've been exploring Rust's concurrency mechanisms and understand that async/await was introduced to handle concurrent tasks more efficiently. It's my understanding that before its introduction, the prevalent approach was to "just use threads". Many learning resources, be it books, articles, or even video tutorials, often present the threaded model as the "old way" and introduce async/await as the "new way". This new approach is said to make better use of threads by reusing them, especially when they would otherwise be idle in the traditional model.

The "old way" often had threads waiting during I/O operations, whereas async/await is touted to be more efficient in such scenarios. I'm inclined to agree with this perspective on Rust's async/await.

However, I've come across a use case related to "thread local variables" or thread context that I'm struggling with. In many languages, concurrent tasks are typically managed by separate threads. For example, in Java, each HTTP request in a server context is processed by its own thread. This allows for features like @RequestContext dependency injection, which I believe relies on thread context or thread local variable in order to work. If the entire request is processed by the same thread, it's akin to having one or multiple "global variables" specific to each request, building them up as we progress trough the request handling procedure and later reading them when necessary. I believe that it's a common pattern in Java to create a "request filter" (essentially a function that is executed by the same thread that was created to handle a request) where (the request filter) sets up the MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) given request parameters, later down the line a logging library or other code can read values from the MDC context.

My question revolves around the feasibility of this in Rust's async/await model. Given that an async function might be resumed by a different thread post an .await, is there a reliable "thread context"?

To illustrate, I've been working with log4rs (as an example) where logs are directed to different files based on the MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) value, which is thread-specific (or thread local). Here's a test program I've set up:

```ini
[dependencies]
log = { version = "0.4" }
log-mdc = { version = "0.1" }
tokio = { version = "1.3", features = ["full"] }
futures = { version = "0.3" }
```

```rust
use log;
use log_mdc;
use std::thread;
use tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // set up the logger
    fs_util::log::init_default().unwrap();

    let mut join_handles = Vec::new();

    // create bogus work
    for _i in 1..10_000 {
        join_handles.push(tokio::spawn(do_stuff()));
    }

    // wait bogus work before exiting.
    futures::future::join_all(join_handles).await;
    
    log::info!("Program DONE !!");
}

async fn compute_the_answer() -> i32 {
    // simulate the answer to everything, should be 42 though
    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    42
}

async fn do_stuff() {
    // Set up log_mdc, internally uses thread locals

    let before_await_thread_id = thread::current().id();
    let expected_mdc_value = format!("mdcval={before_await_thread_id:?}");

    log_mdc::insert("key", expected_mdc_value.clone());

    compute_the_answer().await; // the do_stuff (current async function) can now be resumed by a different thread, hopefully it happens al least once

    let after_await_thread_id = thread::current().id();

    // verify whether the log_mdc is still set up correctly

    let retrieved_mdc_value = log_mdc::get("key", |opt| {opt.map(|s| s.to_string())});

    match retrieved_mdc_value {
        Some(value) => {
            if value != expected_mdc_value {
                if before_await_thread_id == after_await_thread_id {
                    // usually the threads don't match, but if they do, it's probably because
                    // the same thread that started executing the first portion of do_stuff also executed the second portion
                    // however between these it also executed some other code which did a `log_mdc::insert("key", different_value);`
                    log::warn!("Some black magic happened");
                }
                log::error!("This is bad, expected value = {expected_mdc_value}, value found = {value}, before_await_thread_id {} after_await_thread_id", if before_await_thread_id == after_await_thread_id { "matches" } else { "does NOT match" });
            }
            else { // value == expected_mdc_value
                if before_await_thread_id != after_await_thread_id {
                    log::info!("This what we want, unfortunately never happens");
                } else {
                    log::info!("It's okay, but it' no surprise either, mdc values are the same, but so are the threads");
                }
            }
        },
        // this probably means the tokio runtime assigned a new thread to resume this future (current async function), said thread never executed log_mdc::insert("key", some_value);
        _ => log::error!("log_mdc value not found"),
    }
}
```

```
example output (I've only seen these 2 cases in my test) :
2023-08-21T18:44:09.051001000+02:00 - This is bad, expected value = mdcval=ThreadId(9), value found = mdcval=ThreadId(14), before_await_thread_id does NOT match after_await_thread_id
2023-08-21T18:44:09.051326400+02:00 - It's okay, but it' no surprise either, mdc values are the same, but so are the threads
```

The output suggests that the thread context can change after an .await, affecting the MDC value. Is there a way in Rust's async/await to maintain thread-local variables or 'thread' or rather "execution flow" context without explicitly passing it around? Any insights or corrections to my understanding would be invaluable.

The way I understand it is that Rust's async/await is meant to write and read like synchronous code. Of course in an example like the following we could use the local variables, but should we require to call other functions (that need an execution context) we would need to actually pass a context object.

Comment: Do you have control over the code that uses thread locals?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In this particular example with log4rs no (i.e. log_mdc), of course one could simply not use MDC and use a different method to establish a context by simply passing around "context" object to all functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the code that uses the thread locals, you can use [task locals](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.task_local.html) instead of thread locals.

Comment: Task locals are good, but they're not really useful. When constrained to an api such as in the example the MDC which is not async.
even if we were to re implement log-mdc it wouldn't be possible to use task locals as the task local api requires a binding to the future.
in order to do that we would have to async/await ize the whole stack, from log to the log implementation to it's usage and macros, although possible, it's not practical.

Comment: @AndreiMatei Just wrap the whole task in `scope()`, and you're good to go. The task local will be set for the entire task.

Answer (score 3):

Tokio can move tasks between threads at certain await points. This is done when Tokio's scheduler decides it would be more efficient to do so than to wait for the current thread to stop running another task. In other words, it tries to keep all worker threads busy, and this can require moving tasks between threads.

In your case, awaiting the result of `tokio::time::sleep()` gives Tokio the opportunity to move it to another thread.

If you need some unit of work to be "stuck" to a particular thread, you have some choices.

- Run Tokio in single-threaded mode. Obviously this can decrease efficiency on systems with multiple CPUs/cores if your tasks would otherwise be able to run in parallel.
- Write your task to be synchronous instead of asynchronous and run it using [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html), which runs the provided function on another thread and gives you a future for its completion.
- Run your task in a `LocalSet` using [`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html).  This function is intended to be used to run futures that can't implement `Send` by restricting them to a single thread, but you can also use it to run a `Send` future that you want restricted to a single thread.

Comment: I actually don't want to 'become single threaded', instead, I'm simply looking for a way to maintain "context" in an execution flow, without passing variables.
This is traditionally done by saving said context in a thread local variable

Comment: Then Chayim's answer is probably what you want.